# Unit-Tests organization

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing

I currently am using the following bit of code to initialize some Unit-Tests in a class:

```
[TestClass]
public class BoardTests_SquarePieceFalling
{
    private Engine engine;
    private BackgroundBoard backgroundBoard;
    private PieceBoard pieceBoard;

    private IFallingPieceFactory GetFallingPieceFactory(FallingPiece fallingPieceToReturn)
    {
        var factory = new Mock<IFallingPieceFactory>();
        factory.Setup(f => f.Generate()).Returns(fallingPieceToReturn);
        return factory.Object;
    }

    private void TestInitializer(Color pieceColor, Size boardSize) {
        backgroundBoard = new BackgroundBoard(boardSize);
        pieceBoard = new PieceBoard(boardSize);

        var fallingPiece = new FallingPiece(new SquarePiece(), pieceColor, boardSize.Width);
        var fallingPieceFactory = GetFallingPieceFactory(fallingPiece);
        var currentFallingPiece = new CurrentFallingPiece(fallingPieceFactory);
        var fallingPieceMovementEvaluator = new FallingPieceMovementEvaluator(backgroundBoard, currentFallingPiece, boardSize);

        engine = new Engine(backgroundBoard, pieceBoard, currentFallingPiece, fallingPieceMovementEvaluator);
    }

    ...Unit-Tests are below

    [TestMethod]
    public void When_Square_Hits_The_Ground_Another_One_Starts_Falling_From_The_Top()
    {
        TestInitializer(Color.Red, new Size(2, 7));

        engine.Tick(10);

        ..Asserts..
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, I think I currently have way too many test methods on this class. I also believe they cover a lot of ground, so I'd like to divide them in smaller test classes.

My questions are:

1. Currently, is this the best way to initialize the tests? I know I can use [TestInitialize] annotation, but that doesn't allow me to pass parameters to the initialization of the fields I'll want to use, does it?
2. I am going to split the current test class in 2-3 smaller test classes. My current idea is to create a base test class where the initialization logic resides, and then make all these new classes inherit from it. The only difference I'm seeing is having to put `Engine`, `BackgroundBoard` and `PieceBoard` as protected fields. Is this a good idea?
3. How do you generally take care of Unit-Tests that are very similar, but that generally have always at least 1 different setup field? I mean, in a lot of my Unit-Tests I have the same `Engine`, `BackgroundBoard`, `PieceBoard`, `FallingPiece`, `CurrentFallingPiece`, `FallingPieceFactory`, etc, etc, but generally one or two of those things are different for each test. I circumvented the problem by defining the `TestInitializer()` method with the parameters I need in each test, but I am left wondering if there is any other way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's clearest to have one test class (file) per class being tested.

So you should have a `EngineTest`, `BackgroundBoardTest`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with what you're doing.  You might want to check this out: http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html